# Android NDK: Could not find application project directory?

Tags: android, android-ndk

At first, sorry for my broken english. 
So, I try to run sample of audio mp3 recording using this source code:
https://github.com/yhirano/Mp3VoiceRecorderSampleForAndroid

If I build the project, i got an error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'ndk-build.cmd''
```

Then I open terminal in AndroidStudio and input:

```
1) cd c:\\ndk
2) ndk-build
```

And also got another error:

```
Android NDK: Could not find application project directory !
Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.
c:\ndk\build/core/build-local.mk:148: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

Ok, i doing next in terminal:

```
ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=c:/AndroidStudioProjects/Mp3VoiceRecorderSampleForAndroid-master/
```

this command give me positive result:

```
[armeabi] Install        : libmp3lame.so => libs/armeabi/libmp3lame.so
```

But if I rebuild my project 1st error come again! Searched a lot of answers but didnt find a solution..
Please help! What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the instructions at [Android NDK: Setup](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/setup.html):

1. *Change to the root directory of your project.*
2. *Execute ndk-build to build the native component of your app, by typing ndk-build at the command prompt.*
3. *Build and install your project as you would a regular Android app.*

It looks very much like you are skipping the first step ("c:\\ndk" is most probably the NDK install directory and not the root directory of your project). Most probably because you skipped the bit in the setup instructions where it says:

1. *Update your PATH environment variable with the location of the directory that contains the NDK*

which would allow you to run ndk-build from anywhere.

If you really want to build the way you've described above you could try adding NDK_PROJECT_PATH to the user/system environment variables - but that may cause mysterious problems when you try to build a different NDK project.

Comment: Changing to the root directory doesn't solve this problem.

Answer (score 8):

I faced exactly same problem for my NDK project. It was solved by only one command. 
Go to your project jni folder which contains **Application.mk** and **Android.mk** file.

```
cd /home/rajib/Desktop/GIT_Code/testProject/jni/
```

Now enter following command

```
/home/rajib/Android/NDK-Manual/android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=./ NDK_APPLICATION_MK=./Application.mk APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=./Android.mk
```

N.B: Here you have to use your own NDK path.
Hope it helps. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't build android project with 'ndk-build' (if you don't use c or c++ for developing android). Because ndk builder is for compiling c or c++ project. I can understand you why you take this error. Bacause you use a library which was written with c or c++, in your project. So as result, you should go to the library which was written c or c++, on the terminal and you write 'ndk-build' and run.

For Ex:

$cd AndroidStudioProjects/OcrTest/**C_orC++_Project**/src/main

$ndk-build

Comment: this does not work for me going to my root directory where all my c and c++ files live and typing 'ndk-build'

Comment: when i lived this problem, this way resolved my problem but why this way couldn't help to you i couldn't understand my friend.

Comment: This presumes you have an **Android.mk** file.  Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: @Igor Ganapolsky, "ndk-build is not recognized as an internal or external command" is what I am getting. I have Android.mk file in the folder from which I am executing the command

Comment: @The_Martian Would you be open to giving Gradle a try?

Answer (score 1):

You're using Android Studio, and AS with the current gradle plugin ignores your Makefile, which is certainly generating errors.

Since the built-in ndk support doesn't support native dependencies (which you need here), you can simply deactivate the built-in call to ndk-build, and make gradle call ndk-build directly, taking your Makefile in account:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

...

android {  
  ...
  sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs' //set .so files location to libs instead of jniLibs
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }

    // add a task that calls regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
    task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
            commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
        } else {
            commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
        }
    }

    // add this task as a dependency of Java compilation
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@ph0b I used your build.gradle but didnt work for me. Now I am using this and this is working fine.

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

...

android {  
  ...
  sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs' //set .so files location to libs instead of jniLibs
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }

    // add a task that calls regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
    task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
            commandLine 'ndk_path' + 'ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
        } else {
            commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
        }
    }

    // add this task as a dependency of Java compilation
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }
}
```